Does the kapania dancers' elasticity arcana allowthe bladed scarf to quality for the tangled limbs feat?
I just want to double check because everything I'm looking at as well as prior knowledge is pointing to yes, but it never hurts to double check ya know?

You need fighter weapon training.
From the PFSRD (emphasis mine):

Elasticity (Su): As a free action, the ... dancer can spend 1 point from his arcane pool in order to grant a bladed scarf he’s wielding reach until the end of his turn. ...

Note that the Elasticity arcana only lasts for 1 turn (not even 1 round).
From the PFSRD, the Tangled Limbs feat:

Benefit(s): Choose one weapon with the reach special quality.

The weapon you choose has to have reach when you take the feat.
Giving bladed scarves reach for 1 turn probably isn't enough for them to count as having reach while you level up, which means you can't meet the prerequisite to choose bladed scarves when you take the Tangled Limbs feat.
However, further in the feat:

Special: In addition to the chosen weapon, a character with the weapon training class feature can use Tangled Limbs with any melee weapon from any fighter weapon group that he has selected with weapon training and that has the reach special quality.

You could choose another weapon, that always has reach, when you take Tangled Limbs. If you have fighter weapon training (normally acquired at level 5) with the flails group, then you could use Tangled Limbs with the bladed scarf while it has reach, even though it wasn't the weapon you selected when you took Tangled Limbs.
